# Project timetable

Tags: tables

I need to do a timetable for a school project. The timetable has to include what everyone of the three members of our group will do in a specific amount of time, very much like this:f[image]

Comment: You can use pgfgantt package

Comment: Have you tried to use multicolumn?  I can't really see anything special about this table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use a `tabular` or `tabularx` if you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l*{3}{|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}|}\hline
       & Alice & Bob & Chris \\\hline
       October & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Read books} & Start Programing \\\hline
       November & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\cellcolor{green}Holidays}\\\hline
       December & Read a book & Write a chapter & Programing\\\hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

One can join column too using `multirow`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l*{3}{|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}|}\hline
       & Alice  & Bob                             & Chris \\\hline
       October  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Read books} & Start Programing \\\hline
       November & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\cellcolor{green}Holidays}\\\hline
       December & \cellcolor{red}                                & Write a chapter & Programing\\\cline{1-1}
       January &  \multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor{red}Read a book}    & Write a chapter & Programing\\\hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can have a combination of multi rows and multi columns too.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l*{3}{|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}|}\hline
       & Alice  & Bob                             & Chris \\\hline
       October  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Read books} & Start Programing \\\hline
       November & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\cellcolor{green}Holidays}\\\hline
       December & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor{red}} & Programing\\\cline{1-1}
       January &  \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor{red}Read a book}}     & Programing\\\hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to join columns for several months?

Comment: @Razupaltuff Sure. Please see the edit.

Comment: would it be possible to extend the 'Read a book' column so that it covers both Alice and Bob?

Comment: @Razupaltuff Yes. Please see the edit.